# How to import Python file universally from the same folder and from outer?

Tags: python, class, import

I have hierarchy of files:
folder
|
classes
|
class1.py
class2.py
test_class2.py
main.py
**Sorry, I can't find how to tab text. Main.py and classes folder is in the same folder.**
Main.py imports from class2.py `from classes.class2 import someclass`.
The class2.py imports from class1.py `from classes.class1 import someanotherclass`.
This works perfectly in case of running main.py. The problem is if I want to test class2.py in the folder 'classes', I always need to change import to `from class1.py import someanotherclass`.
So is there any universal way to import it in both cases, so as for main.py and class2.py work properly?

Comment: You could wrap your import in a try...except and in case of an ImportError you import your module from "the other" location.

Comment: @MikeScotty Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `relative imports` is what you are looking for:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

main.py

```
from classes.class2 import someclass
```

classes/class2.py

```
from .class1 import someanotherclass
```